# How to Subtract one cell to next row cell in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

is it possible subtract one cell value new row cell value in sqlite?

Example:

```
  | d1   | 
  |3000  | 
  |4000  |
```

In d1 column,
 cell no.1 (3000) - cell no.2(4000)

**Edit:**

```
   Date       id   idCl nameCl    opening   dr     closing
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon        0      2000     2000
22-9-2016    20L   CL-J  Jon       2000    1000     3000
1-9-2016     10L   CL-J  Jon       3000    2000     5000
```

Comment: "cell value" doesn't make sense in the SQL context.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is onther way to do this?

Comment: I think you mean `ROWS`, cells are excel. But what define who is cell 1 and cell 2? d1 value?

Comment: What is the logic? Why do you need to subtract across rows? Is it just adjacent rows? By id? We need more info to help.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, because are only two rows you can use

```
 SELECT MIN(d1) - MAX(d1)
 FROM YourTable.
```

Now if you have a bigger table you need do a `SELF JOIN`. But then you need provide more data and desire ouput.

Comment: Carlos, Yes have large data can you give me any example with SELF JOIN join?

Comment: can you provide more data and desire output? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I want final result like that.

Comment: again you need to learn how to ask. You need provide sample data and desire output. not sure what you post but you miss one and label your data properly. Also explain the logic on how go from data to result